# Grabbing full file version of an exe in Python

Tags: python, winapi

I was wondering if there was a easy way to grab the full file version of an exe in python (for instance if you right click into a file's properties and go to Details, you will find something like **File Version 1.1.1.0**).

I found something close by using `win32api.GetFileVersionInfo`, however when listing the file properties, under `FileVersionLS` it seems to have given only one digit, the far right digit of the file version (so in the case of the example above it gave the 0 in 1.1.1.0) when I needed the whole version number.

Hopefully this makes sense, please let me know if there is something I need to elaborate on.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileVersionLS` and `FileVersionMS` act together to represent the complete version number as a 64-bit integer:

> `dwFileVersionMS`
>
> Type: DWORD
>
> The most significant 32 bits of the file's binary version number. This member is used with dwFileVersionLS to form a 64-bit value used for numeric comparisons.
>
> `dwFileVersionLS`
>
> Type: DWORD
>
> The least significant 32 bits of the file's binary version number. This member is used with dwFileVersionMS to form a 64-bit value used for numeric comparisons.

They are each bit-packed with two 16-bit numbers, so you have to bit-shift out the individual numbers. You can use `win32api.LOWORD()` and `win32api.HIWORD()` for that, eg:

```py
def get_file_version(self, path):
    info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(path, '\\')
    ms = info['FileVersionMS']
    ls = info['FileVersionLS']
    return (win32api.HIWORD(ms), win32api.LOWORD(ms),
            win32api.HIWORD(ls), win32api.LOWORD(ls))
```